# Valor erróneo en matriz dinámica C++

Tags: c++

Tengo una clase que tiene como atributo una matriz bidimensional dinámica:

```
int **terrain;
```

La matriz la genero de la siguiente forma:

```
void Terrain::generateTerrain() {
    terrain = new int *[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        terrain[i] = new int[cols];
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            terrain[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Creo un método `getter` a la matriz:

```
int **Terrain::get_terrain() const { 
    return terrain; 
}
```

Los valores de la matriz son tomados de un archivo, en otra clase:

```
Terrain *Gui::readFileAndLoadData(std::string *path) {
    string line;
    ifstream ifile(*path);
    int rows, cols, max, ground_desired, x_tractor, y_tractor;

    // Codigo para dar valor a las variables anteriores 

    Terrain terrain(rows, cols, max, ground_desired, x_tractor, y_tractor);
    Terrain *terrain_ptr = &terrain;
    terrain_ptr->generateTerrain();
    int **terrain_representation = terrain_ptr->get_terrain();

    for (int i = 0; i < terrain.get_rows(); i++) {
        vector<string> new_line;
        getline(ifile, line);
        istringstream input(line);
        copy(istream_iterator<string>(input),
             istream_iterator<string>(),
             back_inserter(new_line));
        for (int j = 0; j < terrain.get_cols(); j++) {
            terrain_representation[i][j] = stoi(new_line[j]);
        }
    }

    return terrain_ptr;
}
```

Si justo antes del `return` intento mostrar por pantalla los valores de `terrain_representation` no habría ningún problema. El problema viene cuando lo intento hacer desde otra clase donde tengo el método `main`. En este método tengo lo siguiente:

```
int main() {
    Gui gui; // clase donde esta el metodo anterior
    std::string str = "./terrain.txt";
    std::string *ptr = &str;
    Terrain *terrain = gui.readFileAndLoadData(ptr);

    cout << terrain->get_terrain()[1][0] << endl;
    cout << terrain->get_terrain()[0][0] << endl;
    cout << terrain->get_terrain()[2][0] << endl;
    cout << terrain->get_terrain()[3][0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Llegados a este punto, los valores en las posiciones [1][0], [2][0] y [3][0] son los correctos, pero al mostrar el valor de [0][0] (o cualquier columna de la fila 0), da un valor totalmente desorbitado:

```
6
-1764852856
2
4
```

El valor correcto sería 6, en este caso. Pero aun me desconcierta más que si cambio el orden de los `cout` por el siguiente, salta un `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. ¿A qué se debe esto?

```
cout << terrain->get_terrain()[0][0] << endl;
cout << terrain->get_terrain()[1][0] << endl;
cout << terrain->get_terrain()[2][0] << endl;
cout << terrain->get_terrain()[3][0] << endl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fíjate en lo que haces:

```
Terrain terrain(rows, cols, max, ground_desired, x_tractor, y_tractor);
Terrain *terrain_ptr = &terrain;
```

Crear una instancia **automática**, coges su dirección, y es esa dirección la que devuelves.

Al ser automática, tu instancia `terrain` **se destruye**; se llama al destructor en cuanto llegas al `return`, por lo que:

- El puntero que devuelves ya no tiene sentido.
- La instancia a la que apunta ya liberó todos sus datos internos (se llamó a su destructor).

La solución es sencilla: crea tu instancia en memoria dinámica:

```
Terrain *terrain = new Terrain(rows, cols, max, ground_desired, x_tractor, y_tractor);
terrain->generateTerrain();

...

return terrain;
```

Comment: ¿Qué explicación podría tener que dependiendo del orden en el que pongas los `cout` de `Segmentation fault` o no?

Comment: @IvánGarcía Muy fácil: lo que tarden en **sobreescribir** los datos de tu `terrain`. Al salir de la función, los datos no se *destruyen*; simplemente, el espacio que ocupan está diposible para reutilizarlo. Cualquier llamada a una función *posterior* es susceptible de hacerlo. Cada función usa variables internas, y son esas las que *machacan* tus datos. Cuanto mas compleja sea la función, mas probabilidades de que pase.

Comment: @IvánGarcía en realidad, es una cuestión de **pura suerte**. Igual haces 5 llamadas a otras funciones, y no pasa nada. Igual a la primera, es mas compleja, o hace mas llamadas internas, y te los *machaca*.